# Javascript - Regex to replace last 4 digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number variable at JavaScript and i want it replaced in last 4 character. Example:

I have a number 123456789 and i want it to be replaced like this 12345****

Is there any regex to do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex `/\d{4}$/`

```js
var res = '123456789'.replace(/\d{4}$/, '****');
document.write(res);
```

[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fU3vS6/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Or using **[`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** or **[`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)**

```js
var str = '123456789',
  res = str.substr(0, str.length - 4) + '****';
document.write(res);
```

Comment: Thank You, that's working exactly like what i want. :)

Comment: @RidhoFauzan : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) as well:

```js
var s = '123456789';
var ns = s.substring(0, s.length - 4) + '****';
document.write(ns);
```